# How to split nested Object into Array of Objects - avoiding for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I want to split a nested Object into an Array of Objects. I am able to achieve the same using two FOR Loops.

Is there any way I can have a better solution, or this is correct?

Below snippet for reference.

```js
 var Input = {
      "English": {
        "v1": "10",
        "v2": "11",
        "v3": "34"
      },
      "Hindi": {
        "v1": "14",
        "v2": "16",
        "v3": "18"
      }
    }
    var Output = []

 for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(Input).length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j<Object.keys(Object.values(Input)[i]).length; j++) {
        Output.push({
          "parameter": Object.keys(Input)[i],
          "machine": Object.keys(Object.values(Input)[i])[j],
          "value":Object.values(Object.values(Input)[i])[j]
        })
      }
    }


console.log(Output)
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your solution. There will be varying opinions about how to go about the task you defined. Your question title says "_avoiding for loop_" - why? The for loop is the fastest iterator available in JavaScript, is well understood, and is reliable. You have not stated a reason for "_avoiding for loop_". There are some, but if you would like to elaborate please do.

Comment: As a side note, you should consider caching data that does not change. You call `Object.keys(Input)` repeatedly - call it once and cache the results for reuse.

Comment: Take a look at `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(Input)) {...}`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks for your comment, yeah for loop is definitely reliable but can't say it as the fastest. Object.entries() and Array.flatMap() looks relevant for large size records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
var Input = {
  English: {
    v1: "10",
    v2: "11",
    v3: "34",
  },
  Hindi: {
    v1: "14",
    v2: "16",
    v3: "18",
  },
};

const Output = Object.entries(Input).flatMap(([parameter, values]) =>
  Object.entries(values).map(([machine, value]) => ({
    parameter,
    machine,
    value,
  }))
);

console.log(Output);
```

Here the `.flatMap()` flattens the arrays created by the `Object.entries().map()` into one big array. It also uses [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pick out the key and value from the tuple which `Object.entries()` produces.